# How to remove all characters after the first colon

Tags: ksh

I have the following string and want to remove the first colon and all characters after the colon printable or non-printable if the file is binary.

```
/dir1/dir2/somefile.txt:09/15/2014 11:25:54 root:sometext:sometext:
```

to end up with

```
/dir1/dir2/somefile.txt
```

Comment: Better get started then.

Comment: I've spend the last 3 hours searching this site and others and have tried all the examples. I've followed every sed example I can find and can remove all the characters from before the first : or all characters after it if there are no other colons. Please make helpful comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `cut`:

```
$ str="/dir1/dir2/somefile.txt:09/15/2014 11:25:54 root:sometext:sometext:"
$ echo "$str" | cut -d: -f1
/dir1/dir2/somefile.txt
```

- `-d:` sets the delimiter to `:`
- `-f1` to extract the first field.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `sed`, or `cut`, or any external program, Korn shell has this feature but-in:

```
str='/dir1/dir2/somefile.txt:09/15/2014 11:25:54 root:sometext:sometext:'
IFS=':' read one two <<< "$str"
echo $one
/dir1/dir2/somefile.txt
```

`IFS` is the field separator.  The <<< is a relatively recent addition to KSH, and is called a "here string" (it is also in bash).  If you are using an old kWh (like ksh88) the use:

```
IFS=':' read one two << END
$str
END
echo $one
/dir1/dir2/somefile.txt
```

Answer (score -1):

```
String str = "/dir1/dir2/somefile.txt:09/15/2014 11:25:54 root:sometext:sometext:"

String result= str.substring(0, str.indexOf(':')+1);
```

Comment: Did you realise this is a question on Korn shell?